# Is it possible to run yolo model in Jetson without optimizing it?

Tags: tensorflow, nvidia, yolo, tensorrt

I had few issues converting yolo.weight model to tensorRT. So, Is it possible to run a yolo model in Jetson with optimizing it to TensorRT ? Will there be the same speed for detection? (Training won't be done in Jetson anyway).

Or is there any other suggestion alternative to TensorRT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, It is **possible** to run YOLO model in Jetson **without optimizing** it with **TensorRT**. The **TensorRT** only optimizes the inference time of your model.

You could try converting it to **TF Lite format** and work from there, but you might need to handle most of the back-end operations yourself.

Also, for both methods, the training is done on the PC and not on the edge device.

You could read more about their documentations here in these links. 
[Tensorflow RT Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorrt) 
[Tensorflow Lite](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite)

Comment: Thanks ! and does converting to .trt engine reduce the inference time ?

Comment: Hi @SaiKrishnadas, this is main the result of the TensorRT optimization. The subgraphs are converted into TensorRT nodes that are optimized. This is thoroughly discussed in this [link](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/tf-trt-user-guide/index.html) . The  general thought is ```You want most of the graph optimized and replaced with the fewest number of TensorRT nodes for best performance``` as stated.